# Sansfont bold not working properly by using older version of XeLaTeX in MikTeXV2.9

Tags: fonts, xetex

I tried with:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}%
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Path = ../fonts/ArnoPro/ ,
UprightFont= ArnoPro-Regular,
BoldFont= ArnoPro-Bold,
ItalicFont=ArnoPro-Italic,
BoldItalicFont=ArnoPro-BoldItalic,
]{ArnoPro}%
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text, Path = ../fonts/ProximaNova/,%
UprightFont= ProximaNova-Regular,%
BoldFont=ProximaNova-Bold,%
ItalicFont=ProximaNova-RegularIt,%
BoldItalicFont=ProximaNova-BoldIt,%
]%
{ProximaNova}%

\begin{document}

{\sffamily\fontseries{b}\selectfont Test}

\textbf{\textsf{Test}}

\end{document}
```

Which produced the output as:

[image]

I need both tag should produce the output in bold font.

I am using some older version of `MikTeX` and `XeLaTeX` (`This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.6.27)`), please suggest how to fix it in this version

Comment: Does the issue arise also with a different font? (Hard to test with a commercial font that is not freely available)

Comment: use `\fontseries{bx}` instead of `b`, or `\bfseries`.

Comment: @DG' Yes, almost it came for all the fonts

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Your suggestion works very well, can you make this as answer? So, I'll accept it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `\fontseries{bx}` instead of `\fontseries{b}`, or use simply `\bfseries`.